# Row value inconsistency

Tags: sql, oracle

Scenario -
We have pack items, which is defined as a composite of one or more items. A complex pack is a one that has more than one component items. Each component item of a complex pack item should be linked to equal number of locations.

**For example**:
Pack `P1` has component `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`. Each item `C1`,`C2` and `C3` is ranged to 10 locations 1,2....10, such that `C1-1`,`C1-2`,...,`C1-10`,`C2-1`,`C2-2`,...,`C2-10`,and `C3-1`,`C3-2`,...,`C3-10` exists. In such case the pack item `P1` also gets associated to locations 1 through 10, as `P1-1`,`P1-2`,...,`P1-10`.

The table `PACK_BREAKOUT` contains the Pack component mapping and the table `ITEM_LOCATION` contains the items to location association. Both Pack and Component are considered as "items" and would exist in `ITEM_LOCATION`.

Ideally, for the a scenario like above the below record-set would be valid

```
PACK_NO    ITEM    NO_OF_LOC
--------   ------  -------------
P1         C1      10
P1         C2      10
P1         C3      10
```

I have the query below that returns result like above for all such pack items.

```
select c.pack_no,c.item,count(a.loc )
  from item_location a, pack_breakout c
 where c.item=a.item
   group by c.pack_no,c.item
   order by 1,2;
```

However, there are some discrepant results like pack no. P2 , P4, and P5 below where the components are not associated with equal number of locations.

```
PACK_NO    ITEM    NO_OF_LOC
--------   ------  -------------
P1         C1      10
P1         C2      10
P1         C3      10
P2         C1      11
P2         C2      5
P2         C3      9
P2         C4      11
P3         C1      21
P3         C2      21
P3         C3      21   
P3         C4      21
P3         C5      21
P4         C1      10
P4         C2      15
P5         C1      10
P5         C2      9
P5         C3      10
P5         C4      10
```

Note that a pack can have n-number of components (as you can see `P1, P2, P3, P4, and P5` have different number of components).

I would like to get only the packs whose component locations are not all consistent. So the desired result set would be-

```
PACK_NO    ITEM    NO_OF_LOC
--------   ------  -------------
P2         C1      11
P2         C2      5
P2         C3      9
P2         C4      11
P4         C1      10
P4         C2      15 
P5         C1      10
P5         C2      9
P5         C3      10
P5         C4      10
```

Note that even if one component does not match no. of locations as the other components within the pack, the entire pack must be considered inconsistent (like `P5`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use another `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select pack_no
from (select c.pack_no, c.item, count(a.loc ) as numlocs
      from item_location a join
           pack_breakout c
           on c.item=a.item
      group by c.pack_no, c.item
     ) p
group by pack_no
having MIN(numlocs) <> MAX(numlocs)
```

This returns the packs.

If you want the details of the numbers, then use the analytic functions for the calculation:

```
select pi.*
from (select pi.*, min(numlocs) over (partition by pack_no) as minnumlocs,
             max(numlocs) over (partition by packno) as maxnumlocs
      from (select c.pack_no, c.item, count(a.loc ) as numlocs
            from item_location a join
                 pack_breakout c
                 on c.item=a.item
            group by c.pack_no, c.item
           ) pi
     ) pi
where minnumlocs <> maxnumlocs
```

Comment: Ahhhh! `MIN(numlocs) <> MAX(numlocs)` was the trick... awesome. Thanks much.